# ESP32 AND CP2102 Serial data reading issue

Tags: arduino, serial, communication, serial-bus, rxd

I have a PCB on which i am taking a 5v - 1A DC power supply , and again providing 3.3v to ESP32 through AMS-1117 3.3v. 
Basically things are not working on when i solder the esp32 on my pcb but things are working when i check it with NodeMCU version of ESP32 ( development board with USB connection ).
My question here is , for a dubugging purpose ( to check the flow of my program ) can i connect the CP2102( USB to TTL converter ) to the esp32 ( RX,TX connections ) and a common Ground ( CP2102 Ground with PCB's Ground ) and get the data on the Serial Monitor on the laptop where CP2102 is connected.

I am attaching the image which will describe my idea more.
Please guide me.

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only if the CP2102 is operating at 3.3V rather than 5V. You said "USB-to-TTL" which implies, to me, 5V logic levels. On the other hand, your block diagram shows the CP2102 running at 3.3V....make sure that it really is. And don't forget to make the common ground connection.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
My TTL has 5v and 3.3v pin , I am using its 3.3v only.
One more query  wanted to ask. is the above diagram perfect?
only ground should be common or the 3.3v pins too.??
while my TTL is powered by laptop through USB cable.

Comment: Only ground **must** be common. There's no need to connect the 3.3V supplies.